# Dynamic naming SerializedName top-level object with GSON

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I am new to programming. I have an app that retrieves json data from api using retrofit but I have small issue, json response contains dynamic top-level object:

*sample.json:*

```
{
  "ISBN:0-7868-5629-7": {
    "bib_key": "ISBN:0-7868-5629-7",
    "info_url": "https://openlibrary.org/books/OL25747413M/The_Lightning_Thief",
    "preview": "borrow",
    "preview_url": "https://archive.org/details/lightningthief0000rior_u3l0",
    "thumbnail_url": "https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/id/7357496-S.jpg",
    "details": {...}
  }
}
```

*JSONModel.kt:*

```
...
data class JSONModel(
    @SerializedName("...") //<-- don't know how to annotate, should contain ISBN:<ISBN number>
    @Expose
    val isbn: ISBNModel
)
```

How can I annotate dynamic top-level json object in this case?

**Update**
It seems like Gson is failing to deserialize without using @SerializedName(...) annotation, I used static value to check and it worked. After I remove the annotation, response body is null. Is this annotation required?

Comment: Would deserializing it as `Map<String, ISBNModel>` be possible?

Comment: @Marcono1234, I tried it and when I get successful response, it still getting null according to logs, code=200, message=, url=... and also includes ```JSONModel(isbn=null)``` in the logs, which means it is failing to deserialize the response body

Comment: "It seems like Gson is failing to deserialize without using @SerializedName"; have you configured ProGuard / R8 to not rename the fields of your model classes?

Comment: @Marcono1234 No, I had no idea that I am supposed to. I will take a look at that and see if it helps. Thanks

Comment: @Marcono1234 I tried with debug and also checked proguard rules. Looks like, it is not the issue, still getting null body

Comment: Ah maybe there was also a misunderstanding; I meant could you try to remove your `JSONModel` class and instead deserialize the data as `Map<String, ISBNModel>`, for example: `gson.fromJson(..., object : TypeToken<Map<String, ISBNModel>>() { }.type)`

Comment: @Marcono1234 thank you a lot, I was searching for solution days. It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing JSONModel data class and using Map<String, ISBNModel> instead solved the problem as it was mentioned by @Marcono1234

In my case, as I am using retrofit:

```
...
call.enqueue(object : Callback<Map<String, ISBNModel> { ... })
...
```

this will solve it

Comment: Can you give an example in DI? @javokhir-matnazarov

Comment: @VahitKeskin You can check that in my repo: https://github.com/fracta7/e-bookshelf